# How to indent second line of a sentence in HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, text

[image]

I have a DIV and inside, a LIST. Each list contains a sentence of the text of various size, from 60 chars up to 200 chars.
I'm beginning the 1st sentence with 3 dots in front, so when the 1st line wraps then the 2nd line's first character is located under those 3 dots.

What I want is to intend the 2nd line so it will begin below the 1st text character of the 1st sentence and all of this to be responsive.

So, how could I make something like this?

Answer (score 2):

The logical thing is to find the HTML tags that are close to what you're after, and then style them the way you want.

e.g. For you, I'd say an Unordered List is pretty much what you have, with some custom styling.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -1em;
}

li:before {
  content: "...";
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum congue elit elit, non facilisis ligula vehicula vitae. Phasellus consequat felis ut mauris euismod laoreet. Cras..</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a venenatis neque. Ut nec odio.</li>
</ul>
```